# Getting Form ID from element of the form

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML page that contains an unknown amount of forms. These forms are populated from an SQL Query using PHP. Because of the unknown amount of forms I chose to set each line as its own form. For submission, I only want to submit the forms that have been changed.

My first thought went to using javascript with an "onChange" function paired to the form fields to determine the form ID. Then I would imput this form ID into an array to be leveraged for the submission at the end.

I tried to navigate through the parent nodes, but because of the way I crafted the forms (using a table) I can not get the form ID.

In other words each row of a table is a form. If a certain row is changed, how do I get the form ID? Below is the structure of my HTML with the form section repeating an unknown amount of times. I am not very competent in JQUERY so I would prefer to do this in JAVASCRIPT so I understand what is happening, does anyone have any ideas?

```
<table>
   <form>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <select>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

Comment: `table` should not contain the `form` element. It should only be inside a `td`

Comment: This is invalid HTML, you either need to put the form around the whole table, or completely inside a table cell.

Comment: If the question of how to get the form element parent is still relevant after you fixed your HTML - every form control element has a property named, surprise, `form`, that refers to the form this element is a part of (if any) ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties, same for HTMLSelectElement, HTMLTextAreaElement, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving different IDs for each forms, then set arrays for each forms and add the childrens of the parent form in those arrays. It won't be a difficult task because you can use PHP echo code between each arrays. Then  make another array, using onChange event attributes or directly by JavaScript, make a piece of JavaScript code that will add the parent form's ID in the previously created array, if any of it's childrens are changed.
You try on the code and we will give you ideas and laws for applying....